# How to change DLT-receive port

Tags: dlt, dlt-daemon

Is there a way to change the default port when running the dlt-receive command?

I tried

```
dlt-receive -o logging.dlt -c 100M 192..254.4.4 -p 3494
```

But I'm getting the unknown option -p.

Info: DLT Package Version: 2.18.4 STABLE

Answer (score 0):

Solved: the "-p option" is available in th DLT Package 2.18.8. So instead of installing dlt-daemon from "sudo apt-get install dlt-daemon". You can build and install DLT from source to get the latest version. Check -> github.com/COVESA/dlt-daemon under "Get Started"

Answer (score 0):

In case of using TCP connection, the way the port can be set for older and current versions of dlt-receive and dlt-viewer (i.e. overridden from default 3490) is by using environment variable DLT_DAEMON_TCP_PORT:

```
$ DLT_DAEMON_TCP_PORT=3494 dlt-receive -o logging.dlt -c 100M 192.254.4.4
```